# Anyone knows how to run automation scripts on multiple instance of AWS for IOS platform

Tags: ui-automation

I would like to run my automation script on multiple iphone (Simulators)

I would like to know how to run single automation script on multiple iphones using python and appium and generate the report. As of now i am using Python with robotframework. it would be greate if anyone can support on this.